# Spark - How to get the snapshot name to which a Hive View or Table points at

Tags: apache-spark, hive

In Hive is is possible to get metadata related with a view using the commmand:

```
show create table myDataBase.myTable
```

This will return something like:

```
CREATE VIEW `myDataBase.myTable` AS SELECT `myTable_20170816073203`.`col1`, `myTable_20170816073203`.`col2`, `myTable_20170816073203`.`col3`, `myTable_20170816073203`.`col4`  FROM `myDataBase`.`myTable_20170816073203`
```

It is possible to run Hive queries from Spark, to later storing the result in a variable, doing something like:

```
val metadata =  sqlContext.sql("show create table myDataBase.myTable")
```

The problem is I am not able to read a specific field from the output, a Dataframe with a single column named result:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [result: string]
```

Which has got the same information as when running the hive query:

```
CREATE VIEW `myDataBase.myTable` AS SELECT `myTable_20170816073203`.`col1`, `myTable_20170816073203`.`col2`, `myTable_20170816073203`.`col3`, `myTable_20170816073203`.`col4`  FROM `myDataBase`.`myTable_20170816073203`
```

Does anyone know another way to get the value of the snapshot to which the view is pointing at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why won't you

```
metadata.first.getString(0)
```

or

```
metadata.as[String].first
```

Comment: Hi, that is what I was considering. Then apply a split based on "." and get the last element. But I had the hope there was a cleaner option.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what @user9787952 pointed out, I found the following approach as a possible was to solve it. But it may be a more efficient way to achieve this.

`metadata.as[String].first.split('_').last.dropRight(1)`

Which will return the date part of the snapshot

```
20170816073203
```